# How can I pass the Platform::IntPtr from WinRT to C#?

Tags: pointers, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I need ti pass a void* pointer from WinRT to C#, Can I use Platform::IntPtr, Or have another way?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  C# can't interpret void * pointers.

Comment: "C# can't interpret void* pointers" It can in unsafe mode...

Answer (score 0):

You might have some success using unsigned __int64/long, which is large enough to hold a pointer in currently supported OS's.